# How to graph the increase of a Counter in Prometheus

Tags: java, counter, prometheus

I have a Prometheus Java counter `myCounter`, and want to be able to graph the change of its value per minute.  For example, if at 12:00, the value of `myCounter` went from 0 to 1, then the change should be graphed as 1. if at 12:01, myCounter increased to a value of 4 (increased by 3), the graph should display 3 at the 12:01 timestamp, etc.

I've tried using `rate(myCounter[1m])` but this doesn't seem to return the correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `increase` operator. It will return the difference between the start of your vector and the end.